# When does the cantillation for Ester and other books change?

Tags: minhag, torah-reading, trop-cantillation, haftarah

Sometimes people read some verses in Ester and other books in a different cantillation. For example, in Ester, some read the verse of "אשר הגלה מירושלים" to the tune of Eichah, and the Mishnah Brurah [690:52](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&pgnum=310) says to read "בלילה ההוא נדדה שנת המלך" loudly. Similarly, in Haftaras Chazon (the haftarah for Devarim), some read most of it in the tune of Eichah.

Is there a complete or partial list of the changes in cantillation for readings?

Comment: The Mishnah Brurah [690:52](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&pgnum=310) says to raise your voice for the second example I gave (I guess some congregations don't have that custom).

Comment: I did come across a book which gave detailed instructions re reading the Megillah, but this was some 40 years ago and I don't remember its name though. Perhaps a google search for megillat esther tikkun or מגילת אסתר תיקון קוראים or some such might pick it up

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46446&pgnum=262

Comment: Thank you. Especially of interest is paragraph 16 where he discusses the (apparently Frankfurt custom) to use the tune of Eichah.